# creating/saving data frames in a R function

Tags: r, function, saving-data

I'm trying to write a function where I can create and save new data frames from a larger one. In this example, I have a large data frame with data from all US states and I'm trying to output individual data frames per state.

```
make.state.database <- function(statename, database) {
  statevar <- as.character( substitute(statename) )
  statename <- database[database$state == statevar, ]
  return(statename)
}
```

When I run:

```
make.state.database(MA, USdata)
```

it outputs perfectly in the console. My problem is that I can't get this new data frame to save. It does not appear in the R Studio environment and I'm totally stuck.

Comment: Try `x <- make.state.database(MA, USdata) `, your data should be saved as the variable `x`

Comment: That works! Thank you very much! Do you know why that is necessary, though?

Comment: by default, r will print to screen any result, rather than storing it as a variable (like a calculator). Think of the arrow `<-` as telling r to store the result in memory. Might be worth your time running through [this tutorial](http://tryr.codeschool.com/)

Comment: Will do! Thanks for your help